# SQL count if (excluding some values)

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to do a count if on some some values in my DB. I want to count the data that does not contain some values. I am doing it like this, but it does not seems to work like that. Any other idea ?

```
SELECT count(case when ABC NOT IN ('%A%', '%B%', '%C%', 
  '%D%', '%E%', '%F%', '%G%', '%H%') then 1 end) as '123'
```

Thank you,

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: LIKE wildcard % doesn't work with NOT IN.

Comment: If those percents are supposed to be wilcards, then you can't use 'IN', you must use the LIKE operator,  but you cannot do it like that,  you must say ABC LIKE '%A%' OR ABC LIKE '%B% OR ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT SUM(
  case when ABC like '%A%'
         or ABC like '%B%'
         or ABC like '%C%'
         or ABC like '%D%'
         or ABC like '%E%'
         or ABC like '%F%'
         or ABC like '%G%'
         or ABC like '%H%'
       then 0 else 1 end
  ) as '123'
```

Comment: SUM(), not COUNT().

Comment: @jarlh Good catch! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have *values*, then use `not in` with constants:

```
SELECT SUM(case when ABC NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
```

If these are `LIKE` patterns, then you can use `NOT LIKE`:

```
SELECT SUM(case when ABC not like '%A%' OR
                     ABC not like '%B%' OR
                     . . .
                then 1 else 0
            end) as cnt
```

Note:  your database might have regular expression extensions that simplify this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to be able to use the wildcard(%)

```
SELECT sum(
    case 
        when ABC NOT Like '%A%'
        and ABC NOT Like '%B%'
        and ABC NOT Like '%C%'
         and ABC NOT Like '%D%'
         and ABC NOT Like '%E%'
         then 1 
     end) as '123'
 from table;
```